# Does iCloud data backup work in the new TestFlight feature for iphones?

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud, testflight

Im building an app that will be in a testing phase on TestFlight for a while. Is it possible to test the iCloud data backup with TestFlight app for *external* *testing*?

I've heard that iCloud doesn't work well for apps in TestFlight and can't really find any info on that... could someone shed some light on this?